# cv2 ImportError (Reason: image not found)

Tags: python, importerror, opencv, apple-m1

I installed opencv-contrib-python using pip on macOS and tried to import cv2 in Jupyter notebook and terminal. But I got the error below

```
import cv2
```

or

```
from cv2 import *
```

> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/zeyu/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/tesseract/lib/libtesseract.4.dylib
> Referenced from: /Users/zeyu/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-39-darwin.so
> Reason: image not found

NB: I'm using a Macbook Pro with apple silicon M1 chip . I don't know if this matters as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when I tried to import cv2 after installing opencv on VScode. This seems to be an error that can occur when building a virtual environment with conda.
I was able to solve the problem by changing "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv" to false.
I don't know about jupyternotebook, but I hope this helps.